# "ID was missing the `virtualMachines` element " error when using azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I have an azure virtual machine scale set and would like to schedule a vm shutdown through azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule resource. But it is throwing the below error, I assume while trying to get the virtual_machine_id. Anyone faced similar issue?

```
resource "azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule" "vm_shutdown" {
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
  location           = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  enabled            = true
  depends_on         = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss]

  daily_recurrence_time = "2000"
  timezone              = "Central Europe Standard Time"


  notification_settings {
    enabled         = true

  }
 }
```

I am getting the below error during Terraform plan:

Error: ID was missing the `virtualMachines` element
│
│   with azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule.vm_shutdown,
│   on 04_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.tf line 57, in resource "azurerm_dev_test_global_vm_shutdown_schedule" "vm_shutdown":
│   57:   virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id

Answer (score 0):

For the `virtual_machine_id` you have to use ID of a `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine`, not `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed that point.

But now I need another a way to schedule shutdown of the vmss instances to reduce the costs.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Curious23 This is a new issue. I would suggest making new question. My answer correctly addresses the error that you reported.